# Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Subject'.

Tags: windows, powershell, email

The emails will not send. Do i need some sort of a Try /Catch loop? What would be the best method of error checking this in Powershell?

I need it to check for each and if one location is not found that it still sends out the others and displays a message saying which Reports were sent and which were not depending on whether the report was found in the folder

Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Subject'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, 
and then try the command again.

```
   #Defines Directory
   $dir = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\reprts\Todays"
   #Sets STMP server
   $SMTPServer = "10.0.0.46"
   #Declares todays time and formats
   $Time = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt')

   $japan = @{            
       Name = 'japan'
       From = "me@me.com"
       To = "you@you.com"
       Cc = "him@him.com"
   }

   $ireland = @{  
       Name = 'ireland'
       From = "me@me.com"
       To = "you@you.com"
       Cc = "her@her.com"
   }

   $spain = @{            
Name = 'spain'
From = "me@me.com"
To = "you@you.com"
Cc = "her@her.com"
   }


   $_Regions = @()
   $_Regions += New-Object PSObject -Property $japan
   $_Regions += New-Object PSObject -Property $ireland
   $_Regions += New-Object PSObject -Property $spain


   ForEach ($_Region in $_Regions) {

       #Searches dir for list , formats 
       $Attachment = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$($_Region.name)*"               -Recurse
       $AttachmentName = $Attachment.BaseName

       $Subject = "$AttachmentName"
       $Body = "Please find attached the Missing Image Report for        $($_Region.name).

       Produced @ $Time 

       Regards,
       John Doe
       "
       #Actions Email
       Send-MailMessage -From $_Region.From -To $_Region.To -CC               $_Region.Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments               $Attachment.FullName
       $Attachment | Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\user\Desktop\reprts\old"
```

}

Comment: The error message you are reporting is telling you what the problem is. Some debugging on your part is in order; have you tried checking relevant values for each step of the process that leads to the assignment to `$Subject`?

Comment: I am going to guess (which I have to do since their is not code showing your call to Send-MailMessage) that you have not added a subject or if you have it is null. The error is absolutely correct as to the problem. In the code you show there is not `$subject`

Comment: You have asked this question twice and your first one was better. If you are still having an issue edit the first question with the relevant information. You can ping the author of the answer there to see if they can help you again. Please avoid reposting questions.

Answer (score 0):

I added some error handling.

The region-objects will be returned, if it send successfully or not, but with a message, where/why it failed

```
#Defines Directory
$dir = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\reprts\Todays"
#Sets STMP server
$SMTPServer = "10.0.0.46"
#Declares todays time and formats
$Time = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt')

$_Regions = @(
    @{            
        Name = 'japan'
        From = "me@me.com"
        To   = "you@you.com"
        Cc   = "him@him.com"
    },
    @{  
        Name = 'ireland'
        From = "me@me.com"
        To   = "you@you.com"
        Cc   = "her@her.com"
    },
    @{            
        Name = 'spain'
        From = "me@me.com"
        To   = "you@you.com"
        Cc   = "her@her.com"
    }
)


ForEach ($_Region in $_Regions) {
    $null = $_Region.add('action','Starting work')
    #Searches dir for list , formats 
    try {
        $Attachment = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$($_Region.name)*" -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop
        $AttachmentName = $Attachment.BaseName

        $Subject = "$AttachmentName"
        $Body = "Please find attached the Missing Image Report for $($_Region.name).

    Produced @ $Time 

    Regards,
    John Doe
    "
        #Actions Email
        Send-MailMessage -From $_Region.From -To $_Region.To -CC $_Region.Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $Attachment.FullName -ErrorAction Stop
        $Attachment | Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\user\Desktop\reprts\old" -ErrorAction Stop
        $_Region.action = 'success'
    }
    catch {
        $_Region.action = $_ #catching the error
    }
    finally {
        $_Region | Select-Object name, action
    }
}
```